# Why is there a difference bet my AdWords/Bid Adjustments/# of Clicks VS /messenger?Source=GoogleAdwords

Tags: google-analytics

I am perplexed in my understanding of the above.

The number of clicks through adwords that I get thru this metric namely **Acquistions ---> AdWords ---> Bid Adjustments ----> No of Clicks** is **280**

When I look up the following metric namely  **Behaviour ---> Site Content ----> All Pages ----> Page In Question = /messenger?Source=GoogleAdwords ----> No of visits via that CLICKING thru that link** is always slightly more i.e **317**

I would have expected both these numbers to be close at best the SAME !!!
Am I measuring something different in these 2 metrics.

There is something I have not understood here - hopefully can someone throw some light as to why these figures are not the same.

Would be grateful - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The difference is caused by passing data.
Adwords is passing only the clicks that are not invalid clicks - often people doubleclick on ads.
Analytics on the other hand is recording the times the javascript code was triggered. 
It's not a bug, its a feature - you can check the invalid clicks :)

+/- 5% - 7% data difference is OK.

**AdWords clicks are more accurate than Analytics data.**